# Link não fica ativo

Tags: php

Tenho um menu do qual quando um item é selecionado, aparece uma div referente a esse item. Porém gostaria de que esse item ficasse marcado. Tentando pelo PHP, fiz da seguinte forma:

```
<a href="?k=0">Todos</a>
<a href="?k=1">Alunos</a>
<a href="?k=2">Professores</a>
<a href="?k=3">Responsáveis</a>
```

E no PHP:

```
switch(isset($_GET['k'])){
    case "0" : $ativo0 = "class=\"uk-active\"";  break;
    case "1" : $ativo1 = "class=\"uk-active\"";  break;
    case "2" : $ativo2 = "class=\"uk-active\""; break;
    case "3" : $ativo3 = "class=\"uk-active\"";  break;
    default : $ativo0 = "class=\"uk-active\"";                                        
}
```

No < li >  referente a cada item:

```
<li <?php echo $ativo0; ?>>....</li>
<li <?php echo $ativo1; ?>>....</li>
<li <?php echo $ativo2; ?>>....</li>
<li <?php echo $ativo3; ?>>....</li>
```

Só que ele deixa marcado somente o **$ativo1**

Comment: poe um div dentro do a

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tem um `isset` sobrando no seu código, e o resultado do `isset` é sempre `1` se a variável existir.

Veja a diferença:

```
switch( $_GET['k'] ){
    case '1' : $ativo1 = 'class="uk-active"'; break;
    case '2' : $ativo2 = 'class="uk-active"'; break;
    case '3' : $ativo3 = 'class="uk-active"'; break;
    default  : $ativo0 = 'class="uk-active"';                                        
}
```

Se quiser usar o `isset`, pode fazer assim:

```
switch( isset($_GET['k']) ? $_GET['k'] : 0 ) {
    case '1' : $ativo1 = 'class="uk-active"'; break;
    case '2' : $ativo2 = 'class="uk-active"'; break;
    case '3' : $ativo3 = 'class="uk-active"'; break;
    default  : $ativo0 = 'class="uk-active"';                                        
}
```

Ou seja, usando um operador ternário testamos se K existe, e escolhemos entre K e zero.

Note que eu removi o `case "0"`, que é desnecessário, pois o `default` faz o mesmo.

Támbém removi as aspas duplas desnecessárias. Aspas duplas em PHP só devem ser usadas quando tem expansão de caracteres como `\n` ou variáveis embutidas.

De curiosidade, uma alternativa mais curta:

```
$ativo[isset($_GET['k']) ? $_GET['k'] : 0] = ' class="uk-active"';

<li<?php echo $ativo[0]; ?>>....</li>
<li<?php echo $ativo[1]; ?>>....</li>
<li<?php echo $ativo[2]; ?>>....</li>
<li<?php echo $ativo[3]; ?>>....</li>
```

No caso não há checagem de k > 3, mas é só pra ilustrar (bastaria um `min( var ,3)`).

Comment: Perfeito Bacco....era o isset() mesmo... obrigado!